# not getting image file ,getting only name of file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i am uploading images /files on upload multiple image but it only shows image name not their mime type using java script

```
<input type='file' name='data[Expensedetail][description]["+i+"][expense_file][]' id='expense_file"+i+"' style='display: none' multiple='true'>
```

where 'i' is value of array coming in loop i = 0,1,2,3 ... everything works fine and i am getting this result on post
[images details][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixaXr.png and using

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
 echo finfo_file($finfo, $file); //$file is the file name coming in above image in array
echo $file;
```

failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Can you show the bit of PHP that gets the actual file from the post request?

Comment: Can you show your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you're missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form` element - without it the server will process the file input as a text field and just receive the filename.